# Incorrect hostname on logstash/kibana issue

Tags: logstash, hostname, logstash-forwarder

There are the steps i have taken so far:- 
1)created a image template from a vm
2) spin new vms from that image
3) each vm (and the image) had logstash forwarder running on it

Now the issue is when i check in logstash all messages are coming under the same hostname of the image-vm.

Say i created the image from vm whose hostname is  "test"
All new vms (even though they have a different hostname) are sending messages with host="test"

Comment: What's the network situation for the VM guests? Do they have their own IP addresses in the same network as the VM host or are they in their own networks behind NAT? In other words, from your Logstash server's point of view, what IP address are they connecting from?

Comment: No they do not have an assigned floating public ip .. i do have an ip on private network